# Making an even at 20 seconds on mediaelement.js

Tags: mediaelement.js

Hi first time using the mediaelement.js html5 audio player, I need it to trigger a php script at 20 seconds (to increase the number of times played in the database already done) but I cant figure out how or where to create the event or get it to seamlessly trigger the script

Thanks for you help

Comment: `code`{if(this.media.currentTime==20) Window.open("http://www.google.com/", "_blank", "");};`code` This is waht I have so far but this will open it in a new tab rather than excuate it on the server, but it doesnt work even at this

Comment: Are you using jquery? Or just plain javascript?

Comment: its a jquery html 5 extention. here the full code for it http://code.google.com/p/html5avmanager/source/browse/html5avmanager/lib/mediaelement/mediaelementplayer.min.js?r=7a98d52e6dd9e3f8e29198732abeeec65e8f257a

Answer (score 0):

You can floor the `currentTime` and set up a variable to check if the event has been fired before.

```
var $video, triggered;
$video = $(videoID);
$triggered = false;

$video.on('timeupdate', function() {
    if (!triggered && Math.floor(this.currentTime) === 20) {
        // Do stuff
        triggered = true;
    }
});
```